# Return 404 if parameter type is wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I would be interested to know if there is some general way to resolve my issue. Lets say some of my Actions expect Id parameter to be passed, but at some point user may try to assign string to Id parameter into URL. As result our action is not fired and 500 exception is thrown in base class. Is there some way to resolve this and throw 404 exception instead?

Comment: How do you want to handle the route information? Configure route

Comment: The route is configured by default Controller/Action, were the action supposed to be Index(int Id). In case i put into the URL /controller/action?id=abc, i get 500 exception

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but can you set up a separate route rule, that takes a string, and just return a 404 from an action that rule routes to?

Comment: Hi, in general this should work. The other thing is if i have lets say 250 routes, creating another 1000 for every route with several parameters ... Could be there some general solution? catchin this issue somewhere in base classes??

Comment: Ok, yeah, in that case it wouldn't be too practical. You can probably extend a something somewhere in the routing realm to change the default behavior, but I've never dabbled with that. Hopefully someone with more knowledge will chime in.

Answer (score 0):

you can put contraints on a route. You can find a good tutorial here

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

then putting a string instead of id will not match the route.

The alternatives are to create an exception filter in MVC/webapi to handle all exceptions and look for the condition, or to create a custom route handler.